# OS Translator plugin replaces the unique feature references (TOIDs) with ogc-fid which is an integer

Tags: postgis, os-mastermap

I've successfully loaded OS MasterMap Topography GZs files into my PostgreSQL (9.5) database, using OS Translator II plugin within QGIS (2.18.18).

But somewhere during the translation process the unique feature references (TOIDs) gets replaced with the ogc_fid ([PK] integer) which is an integer instead of the TOIDs in the GZs files. Here is a screenshot of data in PostgreSQL table:

[image]

Does anybody know how I can get the TOID into the PostGIS?

Comment: You should probably state what actual command you ran. Looking through the ostranslater source code, https://github.com/lutraconsulting/ostranslator-ii, I would imagine the problem is that the ogr2ogr switch GML_EXPOSE_FID is set to NO.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. When using the OS translator plugin to import Ordnance Survey MasterMap Topography into PostgreSQL database you should deselect the option for "Import boundary features (Ignore FID)."

[image]